# Как скачать файл разных форматов по ссылке на амазон

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как можно реализовать скачивание в браузере средствами `js`, файлов по ссылке, например `https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/teeps-media-library/11/8648ea5fba-1540453245/5d01c6968da75.pdf`, при этом чтобы нативный загрузчик браузера([на примере хрома](http://joxi.ru/D2PzZD4UqX9MYr)).
Форматы могут быть [разные](http://joxi.ru/BA05ZpMTMokB9r).

Comment: Гм, из-за отсутствия конкретики в вопросе могу предложить вот такое `<a href="https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/teeps-media-library/11/8648ea5fba-1540453245/5d01c6968da75.pdf" download>download</a>`

Comment: в общем случае для этого не нужен js

Comment: `const url = 'https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/teeps-media-library/11/8648ea5fba-1540453245/5d01c6968da75.pdf';
const link = document.createElement('a'); 
link.href = url;
link.setAttribute('download', 'test.pdf');
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();` Это не совсем решение, поэтому сюда.